# How to append to an itertools generator

Tags: python, python-itertools

Is there a simple way to append an integer to each item in an itertools iterator? If I use `itertools.product`, I do not receive the expected output. For example:

```
>>> for i in itertools.product(itertools.combinations(np.arange(4),2),(4,)): 
...   print(i) 
...    
((0, 1), 4)
((0, 2), 4)
((0, 3), 4)
((1, 2), 4)
((1, 3), 4)
((2, 3), 4)
```

But I would expect (and I want) is

```
>>> for i in itertools.product(itertools.combinations(np.arange(4),2),(4,)): 
...   print(i) 
...    
(0, 1, 4)
(0, 2, 4)
(0, 3, 4)
(1, 2, 4)
(1, 3, 4)
(2, 3, 4)
```

I know that I can "flatten" the output, but I would rather construct the iterator to produce tuples, not tuples of tuples.

I have many different iterators floating around, and I want to keep the code the same for `product`s of itertool iterators and plain itertool iterators

Comment: This might be too simplistic, but what about doing `x = list(i); x.append(4)` then printing `tuple(x)` ?

Comment: I have many different iterators floating around, and I want to keep the code the same for `product`s of itertool iterators and plain itertool iterators.

Comment: You could use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map): `for i in map(lambda x: x + (4,), combinations(range(4), 2)): print(i)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two alternatives each produce an iterator. In the first case, the iterator is created by a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression). In the second, the iterator is created by the use of a [generator function](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions).

```
In [9]: for i in (tup + (4,) for tup in itertools.combinations(np.arange(4),2)):
   ...:     print(i)
   ...:     
(0, 1, 4)
(0, 2, 4)
(0, 3, 4)
(1, 2, 4)
(1, 3, 4)
(2, 3, 4)

In [10]:
```

A generator function might be more readable at the call site, especially if the function name describes its behavior.

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

def adder(it, addend):
    for x in it:
        yield x + addend

for i in adder(itertools.combinations(np.arange(4),2), (4,)):
    print(i)
```

Comment: Yes, `(tup + (4,) for tup in itertools.combinations(np.arange(4),2))` does produce a generator! Thank you